# Why a div with text inside dont fit the text dimension?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a text inside. Why the height of  the div don't fit exactly the height of the text?

How i can fit the size of the text with the parent div?

[Here](https://codepen.io/alessandroinfo/pen/jONgmJX) is a code replication.

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the height of the div don't fit exactly the height of the text"? The height is determined by the `line-height` of the text content, not the actual size of the letters. So if you like the div to take on the height of exactli the letter "t" from top to bottom, that won't be possible without manually adapting the `line-height` property. Imagine if you had an upper-case letter in the text or a letter with a descender like g or j - if there wasn't a fixed line height on elements containing a text node, the height would vary depending on the content, which is not feasible.

Comment: Also, you have to take in account that the line-height includes a small spacing, so that when you have two lines of text, the bottom of the letters of upper line don't touch the top of the letters of lower line

Comment: Is wrong if i add `line-height: 1;` forcing to minimum size? So i can have a div adapted to the text height.

Comment: don't forget that you have character like `jpq` and `TEXT` and `ÂË`. There is a space reserved for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @constantin-groß and @kaddath.

My solution based on the comment of the user writed above is:

CSS

`.text{
    line-height: 1;
}`

Full example [here](https://codepen.io/alessandroinfo/pen/jONgmJX).

I found it helpful to read [this article](https://smad.jmu.edu/shen/webtype/lineheight.html) about line-height and font-size.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.

Consider font size as 12px. The default value of line-height is normal(1.2em)
so the line height of the text inside the division is calculated as  1.2*12

here 12 is the font size and 1.2 is the line height.

So in order to make the height of the division and the text same you need to change the line-height as something like 40% less than the text-height
for 20px I have given 12 s

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border:solid;
  line-height:12px;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<div>text  TEXT ÂË.</div>
```

Without line-height

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border:solid;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<div>text  TEXT ÂË.</div>
```

Note: This is for normal text only for special characters you need to change the line-height accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use light-height:0.66

```css
div { 
   font-size: 20px;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 0.66;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

Alternative to line height, you can adjust the margin of the text instead:

```css
div { 
    position: relative;
    height: 16px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: #00f;
}

p {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```